# Reading values from text file and then adding each value to a dict that is appended to a list

Tags: python

I open a file where each line represent one student with information.
Stored like this:

```
41097-xxkx:Johansson Elin:TE20:290
```

Where every value is seperated with a `":"` Next line is new student and so on.

With this I'm going to add the values to a dict, so every student gets a dict of "prsnummer", "namn" and so on. Those dicts will then be stored in a list.

```
# How I think about dealing with it.
# Tho stripping every part, and adding to dict was harder.

with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        """
        Do something
        """  

# How txt files look like. Each value is seperated with a :
# 040512-xxkx:Valek Kevin:TE20:280
# 041097-xxkx:Johansson Elin:TE20:290

# In the end it will look like:
list_of_dicts = [
{"prsnummer" : "040512-xxkx", "namn" : "Valek Kevin", "Klass" : "TE20", "Merit" : "280"},
{"prsnummer" : "041097-xxkx", "namn" : "Johansson Elin", "Klass" : "TE20", "Merit" : "290"}
]

# (Merit is meant to be stored as a str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the line on the colon, then construct a dictionary using the keys you listed above for each line.

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    list_of_dicts = []
    keys = ["prsnummer", "namn", "Klass", "Merit"]
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(':')
        list_of_dicts.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite strightforward

```
list_of_dicts = []
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    curr_dict = {}
    for line in f:
        values = line.split(":") 
        curr_dict["prsnummer"] = values[0]
        curr_dict["namn"] = values[1]
        curr_dict["Klass"] = values[2]
        curr_dict["Merit"] = values[3]
    list_of_dicts.append(curr_dict)
```

basically you parse your line splitting the string on the ":" character and then extract the info based on the list position

splitting the string `"040512-xxkx:Valek Kevin:TE20:280"` on the char `":"` for example, will generate this `values` list

```
values = line.split(":")
# ["040512-xxkx", "Valek Kevin", "TE20", "280"]
```

- in position 0 (values[0] ) you have the string "040512-xxkx"
- in position 1 (values[1] ) you have the string "Valek Kevin"
- in position 2 (values[2] ) you have the string "TE20"
- in position 2 (values[3] ) you have the string "280"

Comment: Well now i feel really dumb. It was quiet straightforward..Should have known that, but thanks for the quick answer